# How to set maxValue in a dynamic way?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Is there a way to send a variable to the maxvalue numberfield config?

I want my maxvalue to be like another field value (the referent).

It has to be dynamic since I can change the referent field anytime.
I don't know what to use, it seems to me that **validator** event only fires at the first renderer.

Comment: what version? extjs 5?

Comment: @CD.. Yes ! I didn't find the tag, but now I've found it, seems that I didn't look so far .. :)

Comment: Use the `viewModel` and `bind` it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API method in Ext 5 for that: [setMaxValue()](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-method-setMaxValue)

Comment: I've used setMaxValue() with a reference and a publishes on the field I want the value and bind it to the numberfield

Comment: Yes, you should be able to bind it as setMaxValue is a setter what is needed for binding.